# Apply Async in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, multiprocessing, pool

I tried to write a simple code for multiprocessing that previously worked in Python3. Currently, I want to migrate my code from Python3.6 to Python2.7. In Python3.6, it displayed expected results, but not in Python 2.7. Some people said I need to use `with mp.Pool() as pool`, but the results were just the same. This is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Try():
    def print_this(self, test):
        print(test)

x = Try()
pool = Pool(1)
for i in range(10):
    pool.apply_async(x.print_this, args=(i,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The Python3 will display this

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But not in Python2. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: My suggestion is to leave Python2: https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, I saw an answer said that I need  to use ThreadPool as an alternative. I don't know why he/she removed the answer, because it actually works perfectly. So, here's my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
# from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

class Try():
    def print_this(self, test):
        print(test)

# x = Try()
# pool = Pool(1)
# for i in range(10):
#     pool.apply_async(x.print_this, args=(i,))
# pool.close()
# pool.join()

x = Try()
pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
pool.map_async(x.print_this, [i for i in range(10)])
pool.close()
pool.join()
```